# Sequelize association cant work on my code,please

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

im recently to sequelize.

I have 2 table, data_track and car_detail. i want to try associate that 2 table but it never associated.

it's always return error 
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: car_detail is not associated to data_track!

please help me

both table have same primary key column name

data_track.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const gps_status_track = require("./../../configs/gps_status_track")

const data_track = gps_status_track.define('data_track',
    {
        car_id:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        off_time:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        nopol:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        wilayah:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        status:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        o_path:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        keterangan:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        last_update:{
            type:"TIMESTAMP"
        },   
    },
    {
        createdAt:'created_at',
        updatedAt:'updated_at',
        deletedAt:'deleted_at',
        freezeTableName: true,
    }
)

data_track.associate = (models)=>{
    data_track.belongsTo(models.car_detail,{foreignKey:'car_id',as:'dataTrack'})
} 

module.exports = data_track
```

*car_detail.js*

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const gps_status_track = require("./../../configs/gps_status_track")

const car_detail = gps_status_track.define('car_detail',
    {
        car_id:{
            type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:true
        },
        nopol:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        wilayah:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        o_path:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
    },
    {
        createdAt:'created_at',
        updatedAt:'updated_at',
        deletedAt:'deleted_at',
        freezeTableName: true,
    }
)

car_detail.associate = (models)=>{
    car_detail.hasOne(models.data_track,{foreignKey:'car_id',as:'carDetail'})
} 

module.exports = car_detail
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

**DataTrack.js:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const DataTrack = sequelize.define('data_track',
        {
            car_id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            off_time: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            },
            nopol: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            wilayah: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            status: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            o_path: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            keterangan: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            last_update: {
                type: "TIMESTAMP"
            },
        },
        {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
            freezeTableName: true,
        });
    return DataTrack;
}
```

**CarDetail.js:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const CarDetail = sequelize.define('car_detail',
        {
            car_id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            nopol: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            wilayah: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            o_path: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
        },
        {
            createdAt: 'created_at',
            updatedAt: 'updated_at',
            deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
            freezeTableName: true,
        }
    );
    return CarDetail;
}
```

**db.config.js:**

```
const env = require('./env.js')

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(env.database, env.username, env.password, {
    host: env.host,
    dialect: env.dialect
})

const db = {}

db.Sequelize = Sequelize
db.sequelize = sequelize

db.data_track = require('../models/DataTrack')(sequelize, Sequelize)
db.car_detail = require('../models/CarDetail')(sequelize, Sequelize)

db.car_detail.hasOne(db.data_track, { foreignKey: { name: 'cars_id', allowNull: false } })
db.data_track.belongsTo(db.car_detail, { foreignKey: { name: 'cars_id', allowNull: false } })


module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining association is not correct.

> car_detail.hasOne(models.data_track,{foreignKey:'carIDFK', sourceKey: 'cardDetailPKId', as:'carDetail'})

In the data track model, the association will look like.

> data_track.belongsTo(models.car_detail,{foreignKey:'carIDFK', targetKey: 'cardDetailTablePKId'})

Comment: I have tried your code but it still give same errors :(